# How do I replace this Ajax alert with SweetAlert?

Tags: mysql, ajax, sweetalert

I'm a long time browser on here for solutions but have never posted... until now!

I have tried all kinds of variations and I'm sure this is simple but I am stuck. I have the following Ajax script which updates a record on my database.

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" id="update"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> UPDATE</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#update").click(function(){
          var fname=$("#fname").val();
          var thestore=$("#thestore").val();
          $.ajax({
              url:'update.php',
              method:'POST',
              data:{
                  fname:fname,
                  thestore:thestore 
              },
              success:function(response){
                  alert(response);
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

I am trying to replace the **function(response)** part with a SweetAlert but I am getting muddled because of the additional code above the alert fucntion. The following is the SweetAlert code I would like to drop in there:

```
swal("Good job!", "You have updated the record!", "success")
```

Can anybody help me with how best to incorporate this into my existing Ajax code please?

This is update.php where the process ends up and shows the alert:

```
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_db');
$name=$_POST["fname"];
$thestore=$_POST["thestore"];
$sql="UPDATE feedback set firstName='$name', store='$thestore' where id=1";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
echo "You have updated the record!"; }
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

congrats on your first question here on Stack Overflow!

I think you can just write it like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" id="update"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> UPDATE</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#update").click(function(){
          var fname=$("#fname").val();
          var thestore=$("#thestore").val();
          $.ajax({
              url:'update.php',
              method:'POST',
              data:{
                  fname:fname,
                  thestore:thestore 
              },
              success:function(response){
                  // alert(response);
                  swal("Good job!", response, "success");
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is absolutely perfect and works like a charm, thank you so much :-)